# Cannot connect into WindowsXP on VMWare Fusion by IP

Tags: networking, sql-server, vmware-fusion

I have a SQL Server instance running on VMWare Fusion (WinXP) on my Mac. My development environment is on the Mac itself and my test server is failing to connect over the divide. VMWare is configured to used bridged networking and I have setup a static IP within Windows on my subnet. I can ping this IP within Windows but there's no response on the Mac side. Any insights on how to make this address visible to my Mac?

Comment: Is the Mac and SQL server on the same IP network? If not, what are their IP configurations/assignments?

Answer (score 0):

Is Remote Desktop enabled in windows? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814590#2